# Browse and show image file in Python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I am trying to write a simple Python function that opens an image file and show it in a window. 
I need to be able to browse for my file, but I can't find a fix for some errors I get.

This is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
import pywt as pw
import tkFileDialog as tk
from PIL import Image

def fct(fisier):
    img = mpimg.imread(fisier)
    arr=np.array(img, dtype=np.float)
    plt.imshow(arr, cmap=cm.Greys_r)
    plt.show()
    print(arr)
    return arr, img
file = tk.askopenfile(initialdir='C:/temp')
fct(file)
```

The errors are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Disertatie/Python/Resources/ASCII/ASCII.py/CHM", line 17, in <module>
    fct(file)
  File "E:/Disertatie/Python/Resources/ASCII/ASCII.py/CHM", line 10, in fct
    img = mpimg.imread(fisier)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1242, in imread
    im = pilread(fname)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1225, in pilread
    image = Image.open(fname)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2290, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
IOError: cannot identify image file <open file u'E:/Disertatie/Date/Results/chm.tif', mode 'r' at 0x0000000007726300>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file needs to be opened in binary mode ("rb")

The tk file dialogue should be able to take a parameter that opens the file in this mode instead of the default (r)

Answer (score 1):

Your dialog opens the file and returns a file object. You could use `tk.askopenfilename` instead (which just returns a filename) and pass that to the `imread` function.

Comment: I need to use this image for future processing. Is there better to use 'tk.askopenfilename' instead?

Comment: No. In your case it doesn't really matter. `tk.askopenfile` returns an open file, `tk.askopenfilename` just the filename. But since `imread` can handle both, you don't need to worry about what mode to use with the latter one.

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy import misc
f = misc.face()
misc.imsave('e:/beauty.png', f) # uses the Image module (PIL)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(f)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You should add some explanation why and how this code solves the problem.